# data-bs-theme of element does not override global

Tags: css, reactjs, bootstrap-5, react-bootstrap, color-scheme

EDIT: I have added a dummy item to my carousel since locally it cannot be fed somthing from the db and now the theme does not work locally either.

Something about the carousel having items if messing things up

END OF EDIT

I have implemented a theme for my site by adding "data-bs-theme="dark"" to the html tag. Now, it works as expected but when i try to add data-bs-theme="light" to an element it only works locally. Meaning, it works on my machine but when i build the app with vite and upload it to the server it does not.

I can see that the child elements get the "light" theme and that it is clearly declared on the parent element but they also inherit bs-theme="dark" and it seems to not allow the parent theme to override.

react/html below:

```
 <Modal
      show={picsShow}
      size="xl"
      onHide={() => setPicsShow(false)}
      className="transparent"
    >
      <ModalHeader closeButton />
      <Modal.Body
        style={{
          maxHeight: "80vh",
        }}
        data-bs-theme="light"
      >
        <Carousel interval={null} indicators={false} fade>
          {pics.map((pic) => {
            return (
              <Carousel.Item
                key={pic.key}
                className="d-flex justify-content-center"
                style={{
                  maxHeight: "80vh",
                  display: "flex",
                  alignItems: "center",
                }}
              >
                <Image
                  src={`./pics/${pic.path}`}
                  alt={lang === "en" ? pic.name : pic.nameEl}
                  style={{ maxHeight: "80vh", alignSelf: "center" }}
                />
                <Carousel.Caption>
                  <h3 data-bs-theme="light">
                    {lang === "en" ? pic.name : pic.nameEl}
                  </h3>
                </Carousel.Caption>
              </Carousel.Item>
            );
          })}
        </Carousel>
      </Modal.Body>
    </Modal>
  );
};
```

This is the inspection of the element locally

[image: local]

And this is the same element live

[image: live]

And i just cannot figure out why this is happening.

I also tried to add "data-bs-theme="light"" to every other element in the tree with no result.

my package-lock.json

```
"packages": {
    "": {
      "name": "about",
      "version": "0.0.0",
      "dependencies": {
        "axios": "^1.4.0",
        "bootstrap": "^5.3.2",
        "react": "^18.2.0",
        "react-bootstrap": "^2.9.0",
        "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
        "react-google-recaptcha-v3": "^1.10.1",
        "react-type-animation": "^3.0.1"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@types/node": "^18.16.1",
        "@types/react": "^18.0.28",
        "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.11",
        "@types/react-google-recaptcha": "^2.1.5",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.57.1",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.57.1",
        "@vitejs/plugin-react-swc": "^3.0.0",
        "eslint": "^8.38.0",
        "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
        "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.3.4",
        "typescript": "^5.0.2",
        "vite": "^4.3.0",
        "vite-plugin-compression2": "^0.10.5"
      }
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

Until this is fixed, the workaround i found is to add a css rule to the classes bootstrap give to the element i want. It's very hacky but it works

```
.carousel-control-prev-icon {
    filter: none !important;
}

.carousel-control-next-icon {
    filter: none !important;
}

.carousel-caption > span {
    color: #fff !important;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```